# pre-train brain js model

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, brain.js

## My Question

---

I just started learning `brain js` and developed a model which gives you category based on the `input text`.

I want to ask that each time running the model depends on `iterations` greater the number of `iterations` the more it will take time but it improves the `accuracy` of the model.

Is there any way I can `pre-trained` my model so it won't let user to wait for the output.

An example will really help me.

## My Code

---

```
// JSON file data //

[
  {
    "text": "my unit test failed",
    "category": "software"
  },
  {
    "text": "my driver is working",
    "category": "hardware"
  }
]
```

---

```
const brain = require('brain.js');
const data = require('./data.json');                 //data receiving from json//

const network = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();

const trainingData = data.map(item => ({
  input: item.text,
  output: item.category
}));

network.train(trainingData, {
  log: (error) => console.log(error),
  iterations: 1000
});

console.log(network.run('buy me a driver'));         // output is Hardware //
```

---

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can separate the script into two. In one we train the network with the data, then save it to a JSON file, using the [network.toJSON()](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#tojson---json) function.

In the second, we load the network state from the JSON file using the [network.fromJSON()](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#fromjsonjson) function, then run it against our data.

**train-network.js**

```
const brain = require('brain.js');
const data = require('./data.json');    
const fs = require("fs");

const network = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();

const trainingData = data.map(item => ({
  input: item.text,
  output: item.category
}));

network.train(trainingData, {
  log: (error) => console.log(error),
  iterations: 1000
});

// Save network state to JSON file.
const networkState = network.toJSON();
fs.writeFileSync("network_state.json",  JSON.stringify(networkState), "utf-8");
```

**load-network.js**

```
const brain = require('brain.js');
const fs = require("fs");

let network = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();

// Load the trained network data from JSON file.
const networkState = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("network_state.json", "utf-8"));
network.fromJSON(networkState);

console.log(network.run('buy me a driver'));
```

Comment: To resolve the error `Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` at `JSON.parse()`, use `readFileSync().toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also save the nn to a function with `net.toFunction()` and use it elsewhere, as described [here](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/issues/97#issuecomment-331903569)